# php appending link data

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a quiz, however I have some difficulties. I am trying to do this:

quiz page 1 > quiz page 1 answers > quiz page 2 > quiz page 2 answers > quiz page 3 > quiz page 3 answers > quiz answers.

After quiz page 1 is completed it is automatically missing out quiz page 1 answers by me adding a redirect. When they have done all of the quiz, I am using this code:

```
 <?php
$handle1 = fopen("/Quiz/answerpage1.php", "x+");
$handle2 = fopen("/Quiz/answerpage2.php", "x+");
$handle3 = fopen("/Quiz/answerpage.3.php", "x+");

echo "$handle1";
echo "$handle2";
echo "$handle3"
?>
```

However, it just get these errors:
Warning: fopen(/Quiz/answerpage1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xx/public_html/Quiz/finalanswerpage.php on line 2

Warning: fopen(/Quiz/answerpage2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xx/public_html/Quiz/finalanswerpage.php on line 3

Warning: fopen(/Quiz/answerpage.3.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xx/public_html/Quiz/finalanswerpage.php on line 4

How can I resolve it by printing everything on them answer pages? I've tried near to everything I can think of!

Comment: The error messages indicate that the files that you are requesting can't be found by the server. Try fopen("./Quiz/.. or fopen("Quiz/... to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: fopen(/Quiz/answerpage1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xx/public_html/Quiz/finalanswerpage.php on line 2

This error message means that the script `finalanswerpage.php` could not open the file `/Quiz/answerpage1.php`.

Since the scripts `finalanswerpage.php` and `answerpage1.php` appear to be in the same directory on the server (`/home/xx/public_html/Quiz/`),
if you drop the `/Quiz/` prefix from the filenames in the `fopen` commands,
I think it should work, like this:

```
$handle1 = fopen("answerpage1.php", "r");
$handle2 = fopen("answerpage2.php", "r");
$handle3 = fopen("answerpage.3.php", "r");
```

Comment: Thanks @peter I know get these errors though:

Warning: fopen(answerpage1.php): failed to open stream: File exists in /home/devstopco/public_html/Quiz/finalanswerpage.php on line 2

Warning: fopen(answerpage2.php): failed to open stream: File exists in /home/devstopco/public_html/Quiz/finalanswerpage.php on line 3
Resource id #3

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `+x` flag with `fopen`? That will recreate the specified file. I updated my answer to use `r` instead (for reading). If you want to append to those files, then use `a` or `a+` instead of `x+`.

Comment: Ok, However, I still get the errors these ones though: Resource id #3Resource id #4Resource id #5 @peter

Comment: Your original error was `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. Then after you changed the paths in `fopen`, the error changed too: `failed to open stream: File exists`. So after you change `x+` flag to `r`, what's the error now?

Comment: The error now is: Resource id #3Resource id #4Resource id #5

Comment: Oh I see. In fact this is not an error, but the output of your script, these are `$handle1`, `$handle2` and `$handle3` you are echoing. What are you expecting? Perhaps the contents of those files? In that case, maybe instead of all the `fopen` stuff, perhaps you wanted simply `include 'answerpage1.php';`

Comment: Thanks @peter. What I would like to do is display all the results, then have a total results being able to use the same variables on the other php files.